# .gitignore not working properly for excluding sub folders

Tags: git, gitignore

I ignore all files except for some folders as shown below in the .gitignore file.

```
  *
  !.gitignore
  !/sample1/test1/
  !sample1/test1/*
```

My issue is , it only keeps track of files under test1 folder which already exist , when i make new file, it ignores to track it.

may i know any solution ?

Answer (score 2):

You can not directly include already excluded nested direcory. `*` excludes everything so firstly you need to negate exclusion for `sample1` directory and later for `test1` subfolder. That will work as you expect:

```
*
!.gitignore
!/sample1/
/sample1/*
!/sample1/test1
!/sample1/test1/*
```

Comment: Thanks , but it still dont track new files under test1

Comment: @Pentagon Just add `!sample1/test1/*` last and it will.

Comment: @klutt : i still cant track new files under test1

Comment: You're right @klutt. Edited comment above. I tested it and works as expected for me.

Comment: @mrf , thanks for your edit, and it work under test1, and may i know if make other sub directory , should add all like above, or there is some way to accept all inherit folders.
let say 
/sample1/test1/test2/test3/...

Comment: @klutt :Thanks, but is there any way to get whole nested folders at once? let say we have many nested folders like /sample1/test1/test2/test3/... in this case how we exclude whole subfolders under sample1 folder

Comment: @Pentagon Configuration from my post above will work in exactly that way as you want. It will exclude from repo all subfolders of `/sample1/` (e.g. `/sample1/foo/`, `/sample1/bar/`, `/sample1/foo/bar/`) but will include `/sample1/test1` and all it subfolders (e.g. `/sample1/test1/test2/test3/`, `/sample1/test1/foo/`).

Comment: @mrf,  When i test it, it works fine under /sample1/test1 but not subfolders on it, do i need to add any extra line?

Answer (score 1):

This works when I try it:

```
*
!.gitignore           
!sample1/
sample1/*
!sample1/test1/
!sample1/test1/*
```

Comment: Thanks Klutt, but is there any way to get whole nested folders at once?
let say we have many nested folders like
 /sample1/test1/test2/test3/...
in this case how we exclude whole subfolders under sample1 folder